# Unexpected value of sum

Tags: r

this is my program in R:

```
mletheta<-function(x)
{
n<-length(x)
temp<-x<=0
if(n==0||sum(temp)>0)
{
stop("ERROR:x must be a vector of positive real values.\n")
}
thetahat<--1*n/sum(log(1-exp(-1*x**2)))
return(thetahat)
}
mletheta(-3)
```

my problem is i can't understand if x<=0, then how sum(temp)>0. as x=-5:-4 then sum(temp) should be -9<0. I don't understand the logic??

Comment: `temp` is not a vector of numeric values, it a vector of logical flags (`TRUE` and `FALSE`). Then `sum(FALSE)` gives `0` and `sum(TRUE)` gives `1`. And so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's decompose the first part of the function:

```
x <- -5:-4
n <- length(x)
n
# [1] 2
temp <- x<=0
temp
# [1] TRUE TRUE
sum(temp)
# [1] 2
```

This meets the `if` statement `if(n==0||sum(temp)>0)`, where the error message is displayed if the length of the vector in NULL (`n==0`), which is not true in this case, **or** if the sum of `temp` is greater than 0 (`sum(temp)>0`). Here, `sum(temp)` gives 2.